How can I remove the NAs from my dataframe to prevent an "NA" bar from appearing using ggplot2 in R?
I am using the starwars data set in R to mess around and try to create some of my first ever visualizations. I am a total newbie to programming in general and R.
I have written the below but it is producing a bar graph with a pesky "NA" bar in it because two of the characters' data have "NA" as their height. I don't mind the 'none' bar because I assume this is showing droid heights which is still interesting to include, but I don't want the NA for gender.
genderHeights <- starwars |>
  group_by(sex) |>
    summarize(
    avg_height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE)
    )

ggplot(genderHeights, aes(x = sex, y = avg_height)) +
  geom_col() + labs(x = 'Gender', y = 'Average Height (cm)', title = 'Average Height of Star Wars Characters by Gender', 
                      subtitle = 'Does Gender Impact Height?', caption = 'From Starwars Dataset') +
  theme_economist()

As you can see I tried to use na.rm to no avail. I also tried using complete.cases and drop_na() but wasn't really sure where to place these and generally failed to use them successfully so not sure what to do to get rid of that bar and move on to beautification of the bar graph.

When you take the mean of the heights:
mean(height, na.rm = TRUE)

You are omitting the NA in the heights variable, not the sex variable. This means you still get the mean heights for the group of sex==NA.
If you don't want the NA in the barplot, then you can do a couple of things:
1: Omit the NA before plotting using na.omit:
na.omit(genderHeights) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = avg_height)) +
  geom_col()

2: Filter or subset the data using filter (or subset):
 genderHeights %>%
  filter(!is.na(sex)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = avg_height)) +
  geom_col() 

Either method gives you the following:

